# Hexlify an integer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

```
file_1 = (r'res\test.png')

with open(file_1, 'rb') as file_1_:
    file_1_read = file_1_.read()    
file_1_hex = binascii.hexlify(file_1_read)
print ('Hexlifying test.png..')

file_1_size_bytes = len(file_1_read)
file_1_size_bytes_hex = binascii.hexlify(file_1_size_bytes)

print (file_1_size_bytes_hex)

TypeError: 'int' does not support the buffer interface
```

Ok so im trying to hexlify the .png's byte length here. i know its because the len() of file_1_read is a number. im trying to convert decimal to hexidecimal. how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but what about `hex`? Integer in, hex-representation out. builtin and easy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with [`x` type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
>>> '{:x}'.format(123)
'7b'
>>> '{:08x}'.format(123)
'0000007b'
```

or using [`printf`-style formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
>>> '%x' % 123
'7b'
>>> '%08x' % 123
'0000007b'
```

---

If you want to use `binascii.hexlify`, convert the `int` object to `bytes` using [`struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> import binascii
>>> struct.pack('i', 123)  # Replace 123 with `file_1_size_bytes`
b'{\x00\x00\x00'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('i', 123))
b'7b000000'
```

You can control byte order using `>`, `<`, .. format specifier:

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('>i', 123))
b'0000007b'
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('<i', 123))
b'7b000000'
```

See [Format characters - python `struct` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters)

Comment: struct.pack( 'i', file_1_size_bytes)
    binascii.hexlify(struct.pack_into( '>i', file_1_size_bytes))
    print (file_1_size_bytes_hex)                                                                      So i was trying to pack the variable,im getting pack_into expected offset argument. whats the offset?

Comment: oops: / sorry i wrote that wrong. i included the assignment and im getting the same struct.error pack_into expected offset argument.

Comment: @Death_Dealer, Use `pack` instead of `pack_into`. (`pack_into` accepts an addition buffer object as the second parameter) https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack_into

Comment: ok so that fixed that error, now im getting, file_test.write(file_1_size_bytes_hex) TypeError: must be str, not bytes.

Comment: @Death_Dealer, It seems like you open the file with text mode. Open the file with binary mode or decode the bytes object before write: `file_test.write(file_1_size_bytes_hex.decode())`

Comment: Awesome thank you for the guidance, ive been stuck with this for awhile now.

Comment: can i use struct.pack turn a 4 byte hex string to a 2 byte string,         (b '\x00\x00\x00\x11' ) to (b '\x00\x11' ) like this?

Comment: @Death_Dealer, unpack it, then pack it: `struct.pack('>H', *struct.unpack('>I', b'\x00\x00\x00\x11'))`. IOW, convert it to `int`, then repack it.